# decorate IEnumerable without looping

Tags: c#, performance, ienumerable

I need to create an IEnummerable of DcumentSearch object from IQueryable
The following code causes the database to load the entire result which makes my app slow.

```
public static IEnumerable<DocumentSearch> BuildDocumentSearch(IQueryable<Document> documents)
{
    var enumerator = documents.GetEnumerator();
    while(enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        yield return new DocumentSearch(enumerator.Current);
    }    
}
```

Comment: You are enumerating over all documents and don't want all documents to be loaded? What you will enumerate in that case?

Comment: You should decorate it when using the IEnumerable

Comment: The code you showed shouldn't load the data from the database. Only when you enumerate the result of the method the data should be loaded. And that's correct, because otherwise you would have nothing to iterate.

Comment: @Aphelion The IEnumerable is used by a third party(KendoUI) grid, so I can't decorate it when its used.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky The IEnumerable is used by a paginated grid to show only 10 rows at a time not the entire query result. But in my code the loop results in loading of the entire result to the server.

Comment: @chadisbad if you want paginataion, then use `IQueryable` data and `Skip()` `Take()` methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The natural way of writing this is:

```
public static IEnumerable<DocumentSearch> BuildDocumentSearch(IQueryable<Document> documents)
{
    return documents.Select(doc => new DocumentSearch(doc));
}
```

When you call one of the IEnumerable extension methods like Select, Where, OrderBy etc, you are still adding to the recipe for the results that will be returned.  When you try to access an element of an IEnumerable (as in your example), the result set must be resolved at that time.

For what it's worth, your while loop would be more naturally written as a foreach loop, though it should have the same semantics about when the query is executed.

Comment: This code does not hit the database when the IEnumerable is created. This is what I was looking for. The result is used by the UI grid to load a few rows at a time, resulting in a faster page. Thanks!